# how to drop trigger of sqlite in Android

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

```
String  sql1 = "DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS Trigger_Insert_"  + table  +  " ;"  ;       
db.execSQL(sql1);


String  sql2 = "CREATE TRIGGER Trigger_Insert_" +  table  +
                "　   AFTER INSERT "+ 
                " ON "+ table + 
                "  BEGIN "+ 
                " SELECT last_insert_rowid(); "+
                " insert into Metadata(NID, tableName , rowId, timeStamp , sync) values(hex(randomblob(16)),'" + table + "'," +
                        "  CAST( last_insert_rowid()  AS INTEGER), datetime('now'),0); END;";

db.execSQL(sql1);
```

It seems  cannot  drop trigger,  because  each time  I  re-execute  this  code  will  alert
trigger  exists  error.

Comment: Are you really executing `sql1` twice?

Comment: Why I  should  execut it  twice?

Comment: I did not ask whether you think you *should* execute it twice, but whether you actually *do* execute it twice (because that's what the code appears to be doing).

Comment: Ok, got it.~But isn't it would be safe with "IF EXISTIS" query? Let me figure out tommr.